# Cordova Push Notification plugin for twilio

Tags: cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, twilio, cordova-plugins

Does anyone know how to integrate [twilio push notifications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/guides/push-notification-configuration) with a Cordova application?

I searched for a [Cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) and I'm only able to find ones that support [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) or [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

I did find some plugins that were severely lacking and not at all a good choice for a production application… I need a good solid plugin one I can use in production.

This is my first time to create anything using push notifications in general so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're checking out [IP Messaging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging).

Currently, there aren't any plugin examples for this. This is a popular request for a number of platforms including React Native, Cordova and Ionic.

I will keep an eye on this issue and provide any updates here.

Comment: just use any firebase cordova plugin and register the token with twilio with the twilio javascript SDK [setPushRegistrationId](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.3.0/docs/Client.html#setPushRegistrationId__anchor)